# PG::UndefinedTable while running rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

In a nutshell, I have a model spec that passes all tests when run independently, but when run with the rest of my specs it fails and throws this error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "organizations" does not exist at character 13
   : INSERT INTO "organizations" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"
```

While in the pry debugging console I cannot create a new record with ActiveRecord, nor with FactoryGirl, but if I connect to the test database via sequel directly from the console, I can insert records just fine.

```
> DB.tables
=> [..., :organizations, ...]
> DB[:organizations].insert(name: "Test")
=> 1
```

I'm using `rspec-rails` and `factory_girl_rails`, with `database_cleaner`

Edit: my `database_cleaner.rb`

```js
require "capybara/rspec"

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, type: :feature) do
    driver_shares_db_connection_with_specs = Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation unless driver_shares_db_connection_with_specs
  end

  config.before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.around(:each) do |spec|
    spec.run
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :deletion if spec.metadata[:js]
  end

  config.after :each do
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Comment: How did you create the table? Did you use migration?

Comment: @archana Loaded an up-to-date schema from the development database, as the migrations are polluted with all kinds of data manipulation and API calls...

Comment: And in test environment it also works fine? `rails c test`

Comment: @MartinZinovsky yes. Everything works perfectly fine, except when this one test is run along with the rest. I edited my question to include my `DatabaseCleaner` setup

Comment: "I cannot create a new record with ActiveRecord", what mistake?

Comment: @ggoha `Organization.create(name: "test")`, while in the pry console in the test environment just before the spec fails, throws the same error: undefined table `organizations`. But via sequel (`DB = Sequel.postgres("mydb_test")` `DB[:organizations].insert(name: "test")` it works perfectly fine

Comment: all another table work correct?

Comment: @ggoha yep, other tables are fine